# Read a .db file, created using Apache's httxt2dbm

Tags: apache-2.2, rewrite

I have a .db file on my linux/cpanel server, created using Apache's httxt2dbm, for the purpose of a RewriteMap.

Someone has deleted my original text file and viewing the .db.pag file in a text editor shows a lot of strange characters, making it unusable.

Does anyone know of a way of viewing/exporting my .db.pag file into a readable format please?

Answer (score 0):

If it has a `pag` ending, this is a SDBM hash file.

You can dump it with this small ruby script (other languages like Python or Perl would also work with similar scripts):

```
require 'sdbm'

SDBM.open 'my_database' do |db|
  db.each do |key, value|
    puts "Key: #{key}, Value: #{value}"
  end
end
```

where `my_database` is the name of your database file without the `.pag` ending.

Source: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/sdbm/rdoc/SDBM.html

Comment: Many thanks for your answer - unfortunately I don't have ruby...

Comment: It's free.  https://www.ruby-lang.org/